# Calling a static method by reflection from PowerShell

Tags: reflection, powershell

I'm reading information on various objects from an XML file and need to instantiate and set values on these objects from PowerShell.

This is a sample where `UInt32.Parse(string)` should be retrieved using Reflection. The problem is the `$mi` variable is null:

```
$o = new-object -typename "System.UInt32, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
$mi = $o.GetType().GetMethod("Parse", [type[]] @([string].GetType()) )
```

The corresponding C# code works:

```
UInt32 o = 0;
var mi = o.GetType().GetMethod("Parse", new [] {typeof(string)});
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need to use reflection?  Perhaps you could use `$parse = [system.uint32]::Parse` and `$parse.Invoke($arg)` instead.